# amp-list css horizontal only showing 1 item on desktop

Tags: amp-html

In the trending stories component (amp-list) in 2nd row of content only shows first item on desktop. Sure it's a height / css issue.

https://www.standard.co.uk/business/media

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a look at developer console and looks like there are a few issues with css. First, to see all the stories you need to set `trending-stories`'s `width: 100%` because not setting the width of inner container of `trending` is making `amp-list` use calculated width which is 102.969px. Then set `clear: left;` in `.trending .section` so the title is at right place.

```
.trending .trending-stories {
    width: 100%;
}
.trending .section {
    clear: left;
}
```

Hope that helps.